# How to record CMD output?

Tags: windows, cmd

Is there a way to record *all* activity in the `cmd` console, they way I can with PuTTY? I want to be able to record not just the commands, but also the output, and I should be able to do this without having to pipe each command.

When a command's output is piped to a file, there is no feedback until the prompt returns. Are there any errors I need to respond to? Did the command get stuck in an infinite loop? Is the command working? I have seen situations where piping the output does not work, whether it be with `>` or `|`.

Bonus would be to record the colors of the text. I.e. is the text output in red, yellow, cyan, etc.

Comment: `I have seen situations where piping the output does not work, whether it be with > or | ` .. that is because these symbols only pipe information from stdout (non error output) unless you use more specialized syntax.  There is another "channel" for error output (called stderr) that won't get included unless you tell cmd to do that.  [See this](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-4-stdin-stdout-stderr.html).  This is not an answer to your question but should give you a better understanding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, as this is not the direct answer to your question, but there is a way to pipe output to the file while still having one on your CMD file. You can apply standard Unix `tee` utility.

You can get binaries from [GNU core utils for win32 page](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm). Not sure how it is now, but few years ago it works like a charm.

Comment: There are also some implementations of `tee` for windows.

Comment: I'm not using Windows for a while, so my knowledge in that OS may be totally irrelevant.

Comment: This still does not solve the problem. I would like to log the user-input, as well as the output, in a single stream/file. I use PuTTY to access remote Linux servers. PuTTY has the ability to create a log file where *everything* is recorded. I would like to do this with Windows's CMD.